# loading a single variable after document loads

Tags: jquery, load, lazy-loading, onload, document-ready

I hope someone can help me here. I'm having trouble loading this variable. Right now I have an image that is being displayed when the document is ready. It has an id to it. So I'm trying to capture that id and alert it, but when I tried using .attr(), it gives me undefined variable. However, when I do the exact same script, under another window load, the first alert gives me undefined, the second gives me the correct id.

My Script :

```
window.onload = function() { //first onload gives undefined
   var imgID = $('.selector').attr('id');
   alert(imgID);
};

$(document).ready(function(){ //gives me correct id
   var imgID = $('.selector').attr('id');
   alert(imgID);
});
```

These two functions are placed inside same page. So when the first alert pops up, it gives the page time to load and then second alert pops up which captures the image id.

So I guess I'm trying to get the id after the page is loaded? Can someone help me on how to do that? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what I wanted to accomplish, I just had to set time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The document.ready should work even without window.onload being there. BTW, you can use jQuery's `$()` abbreviation for document.ready:

```
$(function() {
    var imgID = $('.selector').attr('id');
    alert(imgID);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to load right after the page loads. I'll get undefined if I load everything at the same time. Thats why I have an example why I'm loading twice.

Answer (score 0):

$(document).ready should be sufficient here as the function starts once DOM has been loaded. You say it works for you so I don't see what the problem is. You can remove the window.onload and use $(document).ready.

http://www.learningjquery.com/2006/09/introducing-document-ready

Comment: It gets undefined if I don't have something load first. Everything is being loaded all together. If I remove the window.onload, I'm just going to get an undefined alert